# Jquery determine if form field

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way using Jquery or just plain javascript that you can derive if something is a form field?  Example

```
<div id='some_id'></div>
```

or:

```
<input type='text' id='some_id'>
```

Is there a way to check $('#some_id') to ensure it is actually a valid form field type like input, select, checkbox, radio, etc. and not a div, td or other element?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

jQuery has an [`:input`](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) selector that matches form fields (input, textarea, select, etc.)

```
$(el).is(':input')
```

Where `el` is a selector or a DOM element.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `is()` to find out the elements type :

```
if ( $('#some_id').is('input') ) {
    // it's an input element
}

if ( $('#some_id').is('div') ) {
   // it's a div
}
```

you can even check for multiple types :

```
$('#some_id').is('input, select, textarea, button');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/qWbwD/1/)

Comment: That won't match `textarea` or `select`.

Comment: Why not change `input` to `:input`...

Comment: @SLaks - Just add more elements to the selector then ?

Comment: @marteljn - I just always try to stay away from jQuery's pseudo selectors as much as possible, and certainly in a selector without any context.

Comment: Don't forget `button` :)

Comment: @marteljn And there's already an answer that uses that

Comment: Typo in your fiddle: please id=test2 is repeated twice, otherwise, it works fine.

Comment: @ian, you could add anything I guess, but when you have to test what type your elements are, you probably should start rethinking something else.

Comment: @adeneo Oh I agree, and I agree with your opinion about jQuery pseudo selectors. I was just saying, to more fulfill the OP's request to check `is a form field`, I thought `button` should be included...that's all...not crazy important :)

Comment: @Ian - yeah, some of those psuedo selectors can be really inefficient, and `:input` is no different. Not sure how it works when used with `is()`, if it just checks the elements type from a list of known form elements or what, if so, that's not so bad, but just doing `$(':input')` to get all form elements in the DOM is not something I'd use a lot?

Comment: @adeneo I'm sure it's not as bad with `is()`, but it still has to be parsed (more than what a comma-separated string of tagnames would be). It looks like `is()` ends up internally using `.filter()` (and `.grep()`) for some reason, for strings. But yeah, in the docs, they suggest **always** selecting/filtering elements in some way before using a jQuery pseudo selector, because of its inefficiency. It's usually easy enough to not use, such as your example